# FuelPHP: Changing the language dynamically

Tags: multilingual, fuelphp

I'm trying to write a `FuelPHP` (v1.4) module with support for multiple languages. 
I have the following directory structure:

```
fuelphp/
  app/
    modules/
      mymodule/
        lang/
          en/
            signup.php
          te/
            signup.php
        ...
      ...
  ...
```

In the global `config.php` file, I have the language and language_fallback parameters set to `en`:

```
'language' => 'en', // Default language
'language_fallback'  => 'en', // Fallback language when the file isn't available
```

When I try to change the language in the module's controller, through

```
\Config::set('language', 'te');
```

`echo \Lang::get('key');` always returns an empty string

It works as expected if I change the language parameter to `te`, directly in the `config.php` file itself.

My module's controller looks like:

```
<?php
namespace mymodule;
class Controller_Mymodule extends \Controller {
    /**
     * Show signup form
     */
    public function get_signup() {
            \Config::set('language', 'te');
            \Lang::load('signup');

            $view = \View::forge('mymodule/signup');

            return $view;
    }
}
?>
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know your problem, but I've wrote an article about it for FuelPHP 1.4. It isn't to take you to my blog, some people appreciate it so I think it can help you: http://www.marcopace.it/blog/2012/12/fuelphp-i18n-internationalization-of-a-web-application

Answer (score 0):

try calling echo \Lang::get('signup.key'); 
I was having the same problem , this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing Lang::load('signup'); instead of \Lang::load('signup');

From what I've experience, \Lang::load('signup'); is referring to the global lang the one in app while Lang::load('signup'); should refer to the one in your module.